# Передача нестандартного типа по ссылке

Tags: c++

Впервые за долгое время столкнулся со следующим явлением:
когда я создаю свой тип и пытаюсь его передать по ссылке, например, в функцию.
То появляется следующая ошибка: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘тип&’ to an rvalue of type ‘тип’

Вот пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef long int li;

void foo(int &i){i = 10;}

int main()
{
    li i=0;
    foo(i);
    cout << "i: " << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Но если, я изменю на тип, на который объявил я, то ошибок не будет

```
typedef long int li;

void foo(li &i){i = 10;}
```

Или преобразую к ссылке на тип, то ошибок тоже не будет

```
typedef long int li;

void foo(int &i){i = 10;}

int main()
{
...
foo((int&)i);
...
}
```

Поискал в интернете и не смог ничего найти, кроме гениальных комментариев от прирождённых программистов, что ссылку надо превратить в const ссылку, короче опустим оскорбления обделенных умом людей.
Если кто может, дайте пожалуйста ссылки на статьи, которые объясняют,
что происходит в этом случае и какие еще есть способы преодолеть эту ошибку.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь привязать ссылку на тип `int`, к объекту типа `long int`. Даже если не вдаваться в детали, разве это не выглядит подозрительно? А если псевдоним будет такой `typedef std::string li`. Ссылка на `int` тоже должна успешно привязаться? Чем плох вариант `foo(li &i)`?

Comment: Непонятно, что вы ожидаете тут получить, если не ошибку.  `long int` и `int` - не родственные типы, соответственно ссылки на экземпляры одного типа никогда не могут ссылаться на экземпляры другого. Использование c-style_cast - в С++ тоже всегда является ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка — это "под капотом" по сути адрес. Передавая вместо ссылки на один тип переменную другого, вы нарушаете корректность обращения к переменной в памяти.

Например, если размер `long int` - 8 байт, а `int` - 4 байта, то при такой передаче вы просто запишете только 4 байта... Вот, смотрите - https://ideone.com/9iRh7s - произошла запись только половины переменной.

Так что первый путь — с указанием *правильного* типа — корректен. А вот второй — с приведением к типу ссылки на другой тип — приводит к неверному обращению в памяти, что ни к чему хорошему привести не может по определению :(